# Infinity and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Are the points $(0 , +{\infty})$, $(0 , -{\infty})$, $(+{\infty} , 0)$, $(-{\infty} , 0)$, $(+{\infty} , +{\infty})$ and $(-{\infty} , -{\infty})$ part of the set $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: $\pm\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$. So none of these is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're looking for a one-point compactification of the plane, you might want to look into the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Thank you. Is this a simplifying convention, though? Or has this result been proven? Or is it a discussion that fits best in a philosophical exchange?

Comment: "Part" is subset? Also: point$\ne$ subset, $(+\infty,+\infty)=(-\infty,-\infty)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Martin: It looks like he's writing ordered pairs, not interval notation.

Comment: @Hurkyl, now I'm undenderstand the "point". :-)

Answer (score 0):

no but they are in the extention of $\mathbb R$ whice note as $\mathbb R^*$